v8(8.3-lkgr) arm64 crash
I have compiled 8.3-lkgr v8 for Android, and I am getting the following crash at runtime.
backtrace:
#00 pc 000000000009d1e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+168)
#01 pc 000000000004bfbc  /system/lib64/libc.so (free+108)
#02 pc 000000000107dcd4  (v8::internal::Logger::SetUp(v8::internal::Isolate*)+632)
#03 pc 0000000000f4c120  (v8::internal::Isolate::Init(v8::internal::ReadOnlyDeserializer*, v8::internal::StartupDeserializer*)+900)
#04 pc 0000000000f4c894  (v8::internal::Isolate::InitWithSnapshot(v8::internal::ReadOnlyDeserializer*, v8::internal::StartupDeserializer*)+8)
#05 pc 0000000001295ac0  (v8::internal::Snapshot::Initialize(v8::internal::Isolate*)+528)
#06 pc 0000000000e861b4  (v8::Isolate::Initialize(v8::Isolate*, v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&)+376) 
#07 pc 0000000000e86304  (v8::Isolate::New(v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&)+32)

It is clear this happens at Isolate initialization time.
I have disabled Isolate logging which is fine with me, and things work as expected (just commented out logger_->SetUp(this); in Isolate::Init which I think beyond disabling Isolate logger, should be fine).
This is my args.gn in case it is useful:
android_unstripped_runtime_outputs = true
is_component_build = false
is_debug = false
symbol_level = 1
target_cpu = "arm64"
v8_target_cpu = "arm64"
target_os = "android"
use_goma = false
v8_android_log_stdout = true
v8_static_library = true
v8_enable_i18n_support = true
v8_enable_pointer_compression = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false

This crash is slimilar to https://groups.google.com/g/v8-users/c/HV18H0PVlSs/m/RUJqT7foAAAJ. But for me, v8 debug build embedded in Android crashed befor entering v8.

Debug builds are for finding bugs, I'd use them. The Release-mode stack trace is not enough to figure out what the problem is. Also, the 8.3 branch is four years old, consider updating rather than sinking too much time into it.
